# 'In doing this' or 'by doing this'? Which is more common in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

*In doing this* or *by doing this*?

Is the following sentence correct as is?

> In doing this, [the products] benefit from greater diversification and wider reach.

('In doing this' refers to the previous sentence which lists various measures - sales, marketing etc.)

It sounded wrong to me but I'm not sure why - I know both versions exist - and haven't been able to find a clear answer online - are both correct, is there a US/UK difference? 
(What about 'in doing so' etc.?)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are both very similar in meaning, but **in doing this** is only used to describe the consequences of an action which is *actually occurring* at the moment or occurred in the past, where **by doing this** can also be used in a speculative context.  For example, one would never say:

> We should start setting the clocks back now. In doing this, we can save time tomorrow.

For describing the results of an action in the future, you can only use **by doing this**.  Accordingly, I think it carries a bit of that speculative nature along in a general connotation even when used to describe a past action, and can imply that the presumed consequence was merely a theory at the time, even if it has since proved out, as in:

> Paul bought cookies yesterday for the whole group. By doing this, he could get everyone on his side.

(but did he succeed?)